# Parse PFObject fetch not working

Tags: objective-c, caching, parse-platform, fetch, pfquery

I'm trying to update `PFObjects` with server information, basically to discard local changes when user cancels actions, but I''m having a hard time. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or it's a bug, it has been a long programming session.

Here is a test code:

```
    PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"UserRecipes" objectId:@"1NOxhVZVXJ"];
    object[@"instructions"] = @"TEST INSTRUCTIONS";
    NSLog(@"%@", object[@"instructions"]);
    [object fetch];
    NSLog(@"%@", object[@"instructions"]);
```

I've tried with different objects and classes to make sure it isn't something related to `acl`. By the way, in one particular `PFQueryTableViewController`, when I change the object with the method above, no success, but when I leave the controller and enter again, forcing everything to be reloaded, the object is fetched with data from the server and local changes are gone.

**UPDATE:**

As I temporary solution, I'm using `[PFObject revert]` to discard changes and it works. But I would really prefer to perform tasks in background using `fetchInBackground`.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. revert seems to fit better...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Wain, in this case, `revert` works fine since the objective is to discard local changes... but sometimes I really need to get new information in the server, in case it was changed by other users. Since `refresh` is deprecated, `fetch` would be the one. Shouldn't the code above work? Even if the `revert` fits better on this particular case?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't documented what fetch should do with local changes so I expect you'd need to revert and then fetch...